# DynamoDB Query Xamarin.Forms

Tags: .net, json, xamarin, amazon-dynamodb

I'm working on a code which generate Event to put into a DynamoDB Table, sorted by EventID. To generate an unique eventID for each Event i generate a random number, then query into the DB if it already exist. If it does repeat until it does not.

I have a problem to query into my DB, my code does not seem to be working. I'm having trouble understanding the way to build te request, for example what is the IndexName field for, when I already say in KeyConditionExpression what to look for.

Here's my code inspired by the doc of aws:

```
    private int getEventID() {
        bool isValid = false;
        int ranEventID = 0;
        while(!isValid) {
            isValid = true;
            Random random = new Random ();
            ranEventID = random.Next (0, 5);
            QueryEventID (ranEventID);
            foreach (int i in _lstEventID) {
                if (ranEventID == i)
                    isValid = false;
            }
        }
        return ranEventID;
    }

    private async void QueryEventID(int ranEventID) {
        _lstEventID = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        using(App.client) {
            var queryResponse = await App.client.QueryAsync(new QueryRequest() {
                TableName = "Events",
                IndexName = "EventID",
                KeyConditionExpression = "EventID = :v_Id",
                ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary < string, AttributeValue > {
                    {
                        ":v_Id", new AttributeValue {
                            N = ranEventID.ToString()
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            queryResponse.Items.FirstOrDefault((i) => { //This is a workaround for foreach loop with Linq. Could not do .ToList().ForEach
                _lstEventID.Add(Int32.Parse(i["EventID"].N));
                return false;
            });
        }
    }
```

If you have any ideas how not to look into the DB each time I'll gladly consider it. Note that _lstEvent could just be an int, but for reason i need it to be ObservableCollection

Comment: Instead of a "random number", have you considered using a `GUID` (`System.Guid.NewGuid`) as it will be "unique" and you will not have to search the database before the insert.

Comment: Never heard of it before. After google, can I be sure it will never be the same than another one ? If so I will definitely use it. But do you have any idea why the query might not work ?

Comment: Microsoft (and the rest of the tech world) has been using GUID/UUID/etc for a long time, you can trust them to be unique ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a "random number", using a GUID (System.Guid.NewGuid) as it will be "unique" and you will not have to search the database before the insert.

> Database developers and administrators may use GUIDs as primary keys for database tables to ensure uniqueness between database servers, at the cost of making the working set size for caching much larger for a relational database server, potentially impacting application performance.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier

So the downfall of GUIDs are they are "larger" in terms of storage bytes and thus memory caching is increased, but they are unique across all users, servers, etc... and you will not have to redo transactional inserts until you hit a non-used "random" number.

Via Microsoft:

> A GUID is a 128-bit integer (16 bytes) that can be used across all computers and networks wherever a unique identifier is required. Such an identifier has a very low probability of being duplicated.

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396